# Help with simple SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to tables as follows;

1. Employees: Name nvarchar(50), Job Title nvarchar(50) and Salary int.
2. Employers: Name nvarchar(50), Job Title nvarchar(50)

I would like to select every item from the 'Employers' table where 'Job Title' does NOT show up in the 'Employees' table.

I know this is a simple query but it has me stumped. 
I'd be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from employers 
where jobtitle not in (select jobtitle 
     from employees
     where jobtitle is not null);
```

I would consider having a jobs table with foreign keys to both employees and employers

edit - thanks all for the not null fix

Comment: If any employee has a `null` job title, this query will return zero rows.  `x not in (null, 'a', ...` -> `x <> null and x <> 'a' and ..` evaluates to unknown

Comment: Wow, just tested that cos I'd never encountered it and it's true. Fixed by adding `where jobtitle is not null` to the subselect, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join:

```
select * 
from employers 
left join (
    select distinct jobtile
    from employees
) emp on employers.jobtitle = emp.jobtitle
where emp.jobtitle is null
```

Itchi's approach is more readable, but don't forget an `where jobtitle is not null` at the end of the subquery :)

Comment: this will not return the desired output unless there is a employers.jobtitle = null. forgot a left join somewhere?

Comment: Don't do this on SQL server, it's not smart enough to understand it is an anti-join.